# Angular 8 does there is any ways to keep the type information in a multiple async pipe?

Tags: html, angular

In angular, in a template we can do a multiple async pipe this way, but we're losing the typing information.

Does there is anyway to keep it ?

```
<div *ngIf="{
              dogs: dogs$ | async,
              cats: cats$ | async
              } as data">
        <!-- data.dogs is of type any instead of Dog[], is it possible to type data ? as 
        data: {dogs: Dog[], cats: Cat[]} -->
</div>
```

Comment: Since this is added dynamically through the HTML it's all DOM manipulation in the angular compiler's eyes. If you want stricter typing on that level you will need to handle it within your TS component.

Comment: I agree with @Z. Bagley. I'd recommend checking out [forkJoin](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/forkJoin) from the rxjs library to combine the two observables into one in the ts file and then using map to cast your results into your object.

Comment: forkJoin seems to be the solution ! Even though it means each time I change either dogs$ or cats$ I have to reconstruct the observable with forkJoin

Comment: If one or the other data sets change often but not both, maybe look at [combineLatest](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/combineLatest)